# EF Linq search results while ignoring special characters

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-5, linq-to-entities

I'm trying to create a LINQ method query where a user can input text for search criteria which will search a table column and ignore special characters when looking for the results.

For example: Inputting "ab cd" would result in returning both "ab cd" and "ab, cd".

My LINQ Method is currently the following:

```
public List<type> GetData(string input)
{ 
    var results = dbContext.table
                  .Where(s => s.Column.Contains(input))
                  .ToList();
    return results;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `DbFunctions.Like` as of EF 6.2:

```
public List<type> GetData(string input)
{ 
    var results = dbContext.table
                  .Where(s => DbFunctions.Like(s.Column, "%"+input.Replace(' ', '%')+"%"))
                  .ToList();
    return results;
}
```

Comment: I should have been more specific, I'm using MVC 5. I'm getting an error message stating that 'DbFunctions' does not contain a definition for 'Like', even after including "using System.Data.Entity;"

Comment: But what version of EF?

Comment: Good call, my repository project was on an older version. Thanks!